# chrome webstore javascript-based flow

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and would like to charge for it.
I've noticed based on the following documentation that the suggested way of achieving this is via a js api
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money

What I don't understand is how do I make sure no end user is tampering with the client's code, causing a failed request to be considered as a successful one (using a breakpoint, and overriding the returned value from the relevant api call).

Comment: I think this or similar topic was discussed on stackoverflow and the consensus was to move the logic out to the server part.

Comment: So why is a company like google even offering this? This seems very misleading. Could you perhaps link to the stackoverflow thread?

Comment: [How protect chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13263934) - from 2012, not sure this is the one I've read though.

Comment: thanks, seems to suggest more or less what do described. Btw, do you know of any paid extension that's been somewhat successful? Couldn't find a single extension that wasn't free

Comment: I don't know but I guess for the majority of use cases obfuscating+minifying the code is sufficient.

Comment: any client side app is crackable, always. users could load your extension locally as unpacked. your key advantage is doing frequent updates with improvements so its not worth it for users to keep hacking it. also, very few users have the skills or determination to do it, specially if you charge under $5.