# Chrome app (CRX) compiled code?

Tags: google-chrome-app

If I put javascript into a chrome application (CRX) will the code be compiled or in any way hidden from view? At least the crx file seems binary, but is it easily reverse engineered? Does chrome in some way "unpack" it such that a user could easily access the javascripts?

MW

Comment: crx is a variant of zip. If you need to hide something, it will need to happen on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRX is essentially a ZIP file (with some extra cryptographic integrity signature).

Once installed, it will be almost no different from the unpacked extension /app that was used to produce it - it will reside in the Chrome profile folder. **The code will be in the open and fully accessible from the same debugging/development tools as you used to develop it.**

There is abosolutely nothing to stop someone from copying/modifying the extension/app for their needs.

You can minify/obfuscate code, but that's [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649620/does-chrome-market-accept-extensions-with-minified-and-or-obfuscated-source-code) by both CWS and Mozilla add-ons, meaning you may fail automated/manual reviews as a result.

Comment: He's right. No matter what you do, people can always access your code. What makes it even easier to view a Chrome app/extension code is the app at the below url which views the source code of crx files from Chrome Web Store urls. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin